# Scala efficiente way to add rules to create case class for 2 fields

Tags: scala

```
 val metaData = MetaData(
      id = metadata.id,
      amount = if (relevant && metadata.amount.isDefined) metadata.amount else image.amount orElse metadata.amount,
      currency = if (relevant && metadata.currency.isDefined) metadata.currency else image.currency orElse metadata.currency
  )
```

so there are 2 fields i want to set for my metadata case class, but i have conditions as you can see, if relevant is true metadata.amount is defined i will take amount from metadata else from image.amount, and if this is not defined (meaninng that the image amount is not defined so the metadata.amount is the fallback)

same goes for currency, but now i want something else:

if im taking amount from metadata i will take currency from metadata, so they have to come together, as well for if i take currency from metadata i will take amount from metadata.

how do you think the code to do that should look like?

Answer (score 0):

```scala
case class MetaData(
    id: Int,
    amount: Option[Int],
    currency: Option[Int]
)

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val relevant = false
    val metadata = MetaData(1, Some(2), Some(3))
    val image = MetaData(4, Some(5), Some(6))

    val sourceMetaData: Boolean =
      metadata.amount.isDefined && metadata.currency.isDefined
    val sourceImage: Boolean =
      image.amount.isDefined && image.currency.isDefined

    val localAmount =
      if ((relevant && sourceMetaData) || !sourceImage) metadata.amount
      else image.amount

    val localCurrency =
      if ((relevant && sourceMetaData) || !sourceImage) metadata.currency
      else image.currency

    val metaData = MetaData(
      id = metadata.id,
      amount = localAmount,
      currency = localCurrency
    )

    print(metaData)
  }
}
```

This is the best possible way of writing this complex scenario in a readable format.

Please accept the answer if it is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd need to change a bit how your model is modelled so that amount and currency are either always there both or absent both.

Something like:

```scala
case class Amount(amount: Long, currency: String)

case class Metadata(id: Long, amount: Option[Amount])
```